# не работают констрейны в xcode

Tags: xcode

Проблема следующая что прицепить к table view controller ячейку segmented controller  пришлось скопировать все ее содержимое на view controller и самое забавное то, что не работаю констрейнты от слова совсем в независимости что ты туда добавляешь. Подскажите как быть
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тут все достаточно просто, вот тут можно все увидеть
https://youtu.be/XFADCiYbQX4